# QLineEdit should have a fixed size

Tags: qt, layout, qlineedit

I have designed an `UI` with Qt but I am facing an issue. In my `UI` I use two `QLineEdit` for IP addresses. They have a fixed width using `setFixedWidth`.

When the childWidget that contains them is set on top with `parentLayout->setAlignment(&childWidget, Qt::AlignTop)` I get the correct width of `QLineEdit` :

[image: childWidget on top]

But when `childWidget` is vertically centered and on the left with:
 `parentLayout->setAlignment(&childWidget, Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignLeft)`
I get a smaller width of `QLineEdit`:

[image: childWidget vertically centered and on the left]

I don't understand why the `QLineEdit` have a smaller width when the `childWidget` is on the left, their width should be the same, as it's fixed.

Comment: What is size policy of your line editors?

Comment: Their size policy is Fixed

Comment: You mentioned Parent Qwidget .. and `parentLayout`, but its not clear what is `parentLayout` ? how it relates to other elements? you could make things clear just sharing your .ui design file

Comment: Indeed it's the parent QLayout not the QWidget, I have updated the picture

Comment: Only if you share .ui file, things might be clear